# Vector insufficient memory while pushing the video file into the vector?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I use the below piece of code to read each frame from the camera and pushing it to a vector. Am doing this to process all the collected frames in the vector at later point.

I used the below code to collect the frames from camera. But after 2005 frames the codes throws the below error.

> OpenCV Error: Insufficient memory (Failed to allocate 921604 bytes) in
>   OutOfMemoryError, file
>   D:\Opencv\modules\core\src\alloc.cpp, line 52

The below is the code I used to collect the frames and push it into a vector.

```
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>

 using namespace std;
 using namespace cv; 


 int main()
 {     

     VideoCapture capture(0); 
     if(!capture.isOpened()) 
         return -1; 
     vector <Mat>  frame;       
     int delay = 10;  
         int count = 0;

                Mat src;     

                while(true) { 
                    capture >> src;                                     
                    frame.push_back(src.clone());                                                            

                    imshow("VIDEO", src);
                    if( waitKey( delay ) >= 0) break; 
                    count = count+1;
                    cout << count << endl;
                } 


                /* I need to process each frame stored inside the vector*/

      destroyWindow("VIDEO");
      capture.release();

   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Extract the frames to the disk and push_back the filenames inside the vector.

Answer (score 5):

You probably are running out of memory like the error suggests.  If each frame is 640*480 (ie quite low res) then 2005 * 640 * 480 * 3 (bytes per pixel) = 1,847,808,000 (ie 1.8GB of RAM being allocated in a contiguous block).

Equally every time the vector has to resize itself it will need to make an allocation large enough to hold the new data, then copy the old data to the new vector then deallocate the old allocation, effectively doubling the amount of memory you need.

Answer (score 2):

As the error stated, your program has reached the limit of RAM that's reserved for your process by the operational system. You can do some things to reduce this problem:

1 - [Encode the image to a more compact format](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imencode), like .jpg. This will reduce the memory used by your frames.

2 - [Save your buffer on disk](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imwrite). As this is probably slow, and you don't want to lose frame rate, probably you will need to use a new thread in a producer/consumer scheme.

3 - Reduce the resolution of the image. I don't know your specific use case, but a reduced image can be suitable for a lot of computer vision algorithms. No need to store all the color information.

4 - Store just the interesting points of the image: It's a very common approach in the computer vision community. Again, I don't know what you are trying to accomplish, but maybe you can do some pre-processing on the image for each frame and store just the relevant points? Maybe you will need some GPU implementation of the pre-processing algorithm to keep the frame rate at real time.

Keep in mind that even if you reduce significantly the amount of memory that you store per frame, you still will eventually run out of memory. Without saving the information on disk, this is pretty much guaranteed.

Comment: 1 -> you can do this only if you have an hardware accelerator. If camera is throwing out frames at 30 fps, you have 30ms to encode.  2-> Saving to disk. This will only postpone the point when you run out of memory. The only solution is to do processing on the fly.

Comment: Are you seriously implying that my answer is wrong? To me, it clearly seens that you are just throwing back a -1. Serious, if you are really implying that encoding an image is not an option, than you are really just trying to flame me. It's used for 100% of any stream service. How do you think that you are able to watch FULL HD with your 10MB connection at 30 FPS? I already used opencv to encode to jpeg in some applications, and no performance hits were noticed, still processing at 30FPS.

Comment: @Chethan And about disk. What's wrong with saving the frames at disk? It clearly will save him some RAM, as him will throw some content of the buffer away. Probably with a normal 7200RPM HD him will not be able to save all frames at 30FPS, but it will clearly solve the problem him is facing for some time (not stated if real time is necessary). Of course, the HD have a limited memory and will eventually run off, but if him combine that approach with all other solutions, it's a completely reasonable possibility.

Comment: @Chethan: 30ms is quite a lot of time but, yeah, you'd be best off with a GPU doing the heavy lifting.  Saving to disk may well just postpone the inevitable but you don't have enough RAM so maybe thats long enough to do what you need to do.  If it isn't there isn't a vast amount you can do except change your algorithm ...

Answer (score 2):

raw frame sizes are huge. You should typically *preallocate* atleast 2 frames and less than say 4, depending on how much jitter there is with camera source. Multimedia systems *always* pre-allocate memory.

so you should typically do..

```
for(int i=0; i<NUM_FRAMES; i++
    frames.push_back(new Mat()); //handle exceptions from new.
```

and then recycle using the frames

```
int i=0;
int curr_frame=i;

while(true) { 
   capture >> *(frames[i]); 

   //show frame

   i = (i+1)%NUM_FRAMES;

   //process frames[curr_frame]..
}
```

You should actually do processing on the fly, preferably on a separate thread. Consequently, your processing time must be roughly match camera capture rate. That is, it shouldn't happen that you yet to process a certain frame, but is overwritten by the camera. If the processing time of the algorithm is variable, such as in video encoder, jitter buffer helps.There will be sufficient number of buffers (NUM_FRAMES), so that encoder can catch up.

Comment: What? Why not just frames.resize(NUM_FRAMES)? And why use vector of pointers instead of objects?

Comment: You realize that pushing back a lot of frames, than start to pushing back again is just causing him more trouble right?

Comment: @IanMedeiros Please read my post carefully. I am only pushing pointers to preallocated objects. Its one time with a fixed memory requirement = NUM_FRAMES * width * height * bits_per_pixel

Comment: I really can't understand how you push a Mat pointer NUM_FRAMES times inside the frames vector, than you start to push src.clone() in the same vector that is expecting pointers, while .clone returns references. I can just guess that it's a typo? using just the capture >> frames[i] would sufice. And even so, probably the code would not compile because VideoCapture::operator>> returns a reference too?

Comment: @IanMedeiros yes it was a typo. rectified.

Comment: One more revision and I will remove my -1. Now why the first loop pushing back Mat pointers, if frame is not vector<Mat *> ? The best approach here would be just a simple frames.resereve(NUM_FRAMES). That's a faster approach than frames.resize - no need to create each empty object - and speccially than your approach.

Comment: @IanMedeiros Yes, one can use reserve. But I chose to keep it simple, since push_back is typically done only once during the entire use-case and for hand-countable NUM_FRAMES and the gain from using reserve is very less compared to that of video processing.

Comment: Serious? You use to do a loop to allocate a vector every time you need to reserve some memory? I can't +1 a answer where such a bad practice is propagated. Just remove that and you will get my 0 instead of -1. It's not personal, it's just how stackoverflows works: good answer + 1, bad answer -1, neutral stays where it is.